# Unable to add text to dynamic radiobuttons

Tags: android

I am trying to add dynamic radio buttons and text to it from String array. I am able to add radiobuttons successfully of same array length as of "application" but text is not displayed..Any idea?

```
private String[] application = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL"};
RadioButton[] rb = null;    

radioGroup = (RadioGroup) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
rb = new RadioButton[application.length];

for(int m = 0; m < application.length; m++) {
    rb[m] = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
    rb[m].setText(application[m]);
    rb[m].setId(m);
    radioGroup.addView(rb[m]);           
}

mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/sound">

    </RadioGroup>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show layout in which radiogroup lying

Comment: Thanks @NikMyers, have added layout

Comment: maybe you're using some kind of dark style, and text should be white, so with white backgeound you can't see it? I'm not sure, but just check it, change background color or set color for radiobutton

Comment: Post ur full MainActivity code and xml. The layout which ur referencing is not seen in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio button text is white that why it is not visible to you.just add below line in you for loop where you are initializing the radio button.

```
  rb[m].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```